# GMail API: Queuing tasks so they don't get rate limited

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail-api, rate-limiting

I am trying to get the emails of a bunch of users on our service. I am first getting a list of messages, and if the message is not in the DataStore, then we fetch them. However, I'm using the deferred library to avoid the DeadlineExceeded error. The current algorithm is:

1. Put each user task on a queue
2. For each user, get the list of messages
3. For each 10 messages from this list, enqueue to fetch the messages 10 at a time.

However, I realized that this also exceeds the rate limit since I could be doing more than 10 queries/sec. When I tried to do only 1 message at a time instead of 10, and included getting the list of messages (which makes 1 network request for each page of emails), I got an error saying I was using too much memory and my process was shut down.
What is the best algorithm so I can ensure I am always under 10 qps to GMail and yet not run out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think hitting the rate limit is a big deal, just make sure you handle the error and slow down a little in that case.  Fetching messages in batches of 10 seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you run out of memory in the scenario that you described, that means you have a memory leak or an infinite loop in your code. 10 queries can be easily processed on the smallest instance possible.

Comment: Normally a reasonable assumption, but does this answer appreciate [the maximum task size is 100KB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push)?

Comment: His task does not cause a memory problem with 10 messages at once. It is reasonable to assume that a task with 1 message is smaller, not larger.